# How to create my own SMTP Server in Java/Grails to send Emails?

Tags: grails, groovy, smtp

I use Grails 2.4.5 and the [Mail Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/mail). I do not want to use an external SMTP server to send emails from my Grails server. Instead I want to send emails from my Grails application through my own SMTP server.

I found [subethasmtp](https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp) which seems to be for receiving mails but I need to send them to other users inboxes.

**How do I create an SMTP server which sends emails?**

Comment: Writing your own SMTP server is not an easy task. Why do you need to write your own? Have you considered using something like mandril instead? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My problem is that my current SMTP server is sometimes down. If there is a free external Where I can change the from address than please post an answer.

Comment: Are you going to delete this question as you did with [your image conversion one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230538/convert-png-to-jpg-with-groovy)  once you get an answer?

Comment: Also, is this windows or *nix? If the latter, then sendmail seems the mind numbingly obvious answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of SMTP services out there and most of them probably provide a free tier. I use (and love) Mandrill (http://blog.mandrill.com/new-simpler-pricing.html), but have heard good things about MailGun, SendGrid, and others. You can also browse a list of alternative solutions here (http://alternativeto.net/software/mandrill/).

To integrate an SMTP service with your application:

- Add the mail plugin to your application (https://grails.org/plugin/mail)
- Register an account with your desired SMTP service
- Create a new API key for your application (within the SMTP service)
- Add SMTP properties to your external configuration file (~/.grails/appName-config.properties) -- assuming that has been enabled

Here's an example configuration using Mandrill:

```
grails.mail.from = you@yourcompany.com
grails.mail.host = smtp.mandrillapp.com
grails.mail.port = 587
grails.mail.username = <mandrill-username> 
grails.mail.password = <mandrill-apikey>
```